# Как удалить первые 2 строки из файла на Python?

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть 2 файла, которые я свожу вместе. Во втором файле первые 2 строки нужно вырезать, чтобы в otput получить "первый файл (fgjf) + второй файл (fxyz) без первых двух строк"

Код без удаления строк:

```
with open(filexyz, "r") as fxyz, open(file1gjf, "r") as fgjf, open(foutput, "w") as fout:
    fout.write(fgjf.read() + "\n Title " + prefix + "\n\n")
    fout.write(fxyz.read())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то такое:

```
    fout.writelines(fxyz.readlines()[2:])
```

Comment: Спасибо, туплю 